# Web scraping with vba error 438 driving me crazy

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, getelementbyid

My code navigates to a URL an internet explorer, and I try to grab a text associated with the name “pears” as follows:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pears").innerText
```

The references Microsoft HTML Object Library and the Microsoft Internet Controls are selected.

The relevant excerpt from the URL is:

```
<span id="pears">text to be grabbed<br>and this text too</span>
```

> I get a 438 error.

The entire code is:

```
Sub GetWebStuff()  
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer  
IE.navigate Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value  
While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend  
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = IE.document.getElementById("pears").innerText  
IE.Quit  
Set IE = Nothing  
End Sub
```

Why??

Comment: `ID` and `ClassName` are not the same thing. - Use `getElementById` instead.

Comment: With `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = IE.document.getElementsByID("pears").innerText` it still gives me the 438 error.

Comment: that's because there is no such thing as `getElementsByID` - it's `getElementByID` - singular.

Comment: Ok, now I tried the singular. It gives me a 424 error instead of a 438 error.

Comment: well, then it sounds like you didn't set your `IE` object to anything. Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: `Sub GetWebStuff()  
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer  
IE.navigate Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value  
While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend  
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = IE.document.getElementById("pears").innerText  
IE.Quit  
Set IE = Nothing  
End Sub  `

Comment: Please do not include all of your code in a comment. Include it in your question instead.

Comment: Code is in the original question

Comment: Execute code line by line with F8 and see if error goes away. If error still there check that your element is not inside a parent frame/iframe element. Can you share the url?

Comment: The error is in the line where it tries to grab the text, i.e. line nr. 5. The URL is: https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/claims?DB=EPODOC&ND=3&locale=en_EP&FT=D&date=19791127&CC=US&NR=4175517A&KC=A&tree=true#

Comment: .. and in this URL, substitute "pears" with "claim1"

Comment: It is not within a parent iframe. Did you try adding a pause before that line?

Comment: Your code works just fine. You probably have the ID wrong. Oh i just read it's in an IFrame. That adds another layer of complexity to it.

Comment: hello @braX! I don't think it is in an iframe

Comment: @QHarr ok, how to grab the text please?

Comment: Did you try the wait before?

Comment: yes, I did. It made no difference I'm afraid..